# iMac nVidia drivers on Bootcamp/Windows XP (9400M)

Tags: mac, drivers, boot-camp, nvidia-graphics-card

I run Windows XP on occasion on my iMac early 2009 (20"). Lately I have been thinking of trying to update my nVidia drivers as it has been hinted that it could solve some of the problems I've been having.

Right now, I'm running the bootcamp drivers, which work. When I go to nVidia's site to [download the drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) and install them I end up with a driver that is unable to go beyond 640x480 at 8-bit color mode.

It could be just me, but somehow the driver shows the card as "nvidia 9400" (notice the lack of the "M") even though [the specs](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP507) list it as the 9M.

Update: Yes, I did try installing the 9M drivers.

Has anyone experienced these issues? Is there a way to upgrade my graphics drivers?

Comment: nVidia is really good however they do have issues with their drivers on occasion.  Never heard of them listing a driver falsely however; usually a driver will only install if it is compatible; you may be having other issues if the card changes 'name'.  Try properties>settings>advanced>adapter>list all models this will show you all possible screen resolutions.  Otherwise roll back the driver try the re-install or contact nVidia; could be a mac/windows issue: get rid of mac lol ;)

Answer (score 1):

What version of Bootcamp are you running? You should be able to tell by opening the Bootcamp Control Panel from the system tray. The latest version is 3.2; if you have an older version, install all of the updates up through version 3.2. If there are newer Nvidia drivers for your Mac which were released in that time, they may be included. You can download [Bootcamp updates](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#macoscomponents) from the Apple Support site.

Answer (score 0):

Apple used to include the creation of a BootCamp driver disk as part of the BootCamp setup process, perhaps there's a way for you to re-create that disk and try that (if you haven't already).

I know that when I've had driver issues with my (admittedly much older) MacBook the solution has been to use the Leopard/Snow Leopard install disk as there are drivers for a number of the components included there. According to [the Apple site](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3777), it looks like Snow Leopard has the drivers on the install disk.